# Hiding Full screen Intent Heads up Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, heads-up-notifications

I have an app which shows [Full screen Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent,%20boolean)), some tutorial and gifs in [HERE](https://medium.com/android-news/full-screen-intent-notifications-android-85ea2f5b5dc1). When device is locked then `Activity` shows up (just like a call), when device unlocked I'm getting clickable heads-up notification, but it have some flaw.. "usual" heads-up notification will "auto-hide" after fews secs, this heads-up won't...

I need a button inside my app, which opens this `Activity`. I can start new `Intent`, but this won't dismiss heads-up notification, it will stay covering `Activity`, which is openable also through this notification... pressing notification then just dismissing it, `Activity` is already on foreground

looking for any suggestion for hiding heads up notification, when attached `Activity` gets opened in other way. Maybe I should remove notification and show again with lower priority, or even in another `Channel`...